# Linker error when using cuSolver

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, cusolver

I am trying to run an example of SVD with cuSolver library available in cuda 7.0.

When I run this code:

[Parallel implementation for multiple SVDs using CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401765/parallel-implementation-for-multiple-svds-using-cuda)

I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cusolverDnDgesvd referenced in function main  
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cusolverDnDgesvd_bufferSize referenced in function main   
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cusolverDnCreate referenced in function main.
```

I am using VS2010, and the `cusolverDn` library appears to be included.

*What have I missed? Thanks in advance.*

## Edit:

VS settings:
Debug >> Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> CUDA C/C++ >> Additional Include Directories >> ...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\include

Debug >> Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> CUDA Linker >> Additional Library Directories >> ...\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\lib\x64;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

Comment: "the cusolverDn library appears to be included": how do you "include" the library? Did you add the library to VS as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276399/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Yes, I did. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: You have almost certainly not added the library correctly.

Comment: I've added VS settings. - @RobertCrovella

Comment: In addition to adding the directory to the library in AdditionalLibraryDirectories, you must *also* add the library itself, by name under the visual studio project configuration libraries under "Additional Dependencies"   Take a look at step 4 in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058864/how-to-include-libraries-in-visual-studio-2012)